# Drupal 7 .inc files in custom module

Tags: drupal-modules

Firstly let me tell all of you that I am a novice to Drupal and trying to Explore it by my own.

I installed MD_FOTO theme from https://www.drupal.org/project/md_foto and its custom module 'md_foto_features' in my test drupal site and its working fine.

I am trying to explore this custom module, I doubt if it will work as this module contains many .inc files like "md_foto_features.context.inc" as one of them but this file is not loaded using include/include_once/require/require_once.

My question is, How is this file being included(loaded) in order to use functions defined in this file ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Sorry for the Inconvenience !!!
I am trying to explore this custom module, My doubt is as this module contains many .inc files like "md_foto_features.context.inc" as one of them but this file is not included(loaded) using include/include_once/require/require_once.
My question is, How this file is being included(loaded) in order to use functions defined in it ?

Answer (score 0):

**md_foto_features** is a module generated via feature. These `inc files` are automatically include via feature modules.
http://cgit.drupalcode.org/features/tree/features.module#n396

Comment: Thanks smsivaprakaash for replying but my doubt is still unanswered. Actually i wanted to know "md_foto_features.context.inc" is there in that module and How this file is being included ?